# How can I solve my problem with sed command in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
#!/bin/bash

current_day = "6"
sed_output=$(sed -E "s/\b${current_day}\b/$(tput setaf 1)&$(tput sgr0)/g" "calendar.txt")

if echo "$sed_output" | grep -q "$current_day"; then
   echo "Value '$current_day' found in the modified output."
   sed -i "s/$(tput setaf 1)$(printf '%s' $current_day)$(tput sgr0)/$current_day/g/" calendar.txt
   #echo "Modifier removed."
else
    echo "Value '$current_day' not found in the modified output."
fi
```

[image: calender.txt]

I keep getting an error message: "sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command"
The code should be removing the modifier and make the value unmodified.

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable logging and see what the actual sed command generated by your code is; one of the expansions is inserting content you don't expect.

Comment: copy/paste your code into https://shellcheck.net including `#!/bin/bash` as your fist line, and fix any errors flagged. If that doesn't solve your problem, please update your Q with corrected code. Good luck.

Comment: Also, note that backslash sequences like `\b` aren't guaranteed to work in `sed`. Read the POSIX BRE and ERE specifications for details of exactly what _is_ guaranteed to work, and if you want your code to be reliable/portable, use only those features and nothing else.

Comment: Not a great question, but better than average for a first time post. I've upvoted already, but hope you will read the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question" in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info and improve your question. Sample input and expected output and **shellcheck**ed code are key to a good question. Good luck.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What version of `sed` are you using?

Comment: This error generally indicates that the output of one of the `tput` commands contains a newline.

Comment: The output from `tput` presumably contains `[` characters, which have special meaning in regular expressions, and need to be escaped if you want to match them as literal characters. See ["Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for recipies for adding the necessary escape(s). Also, `$(printf '%s' $current_day)` is unnecessarily complicated (unless the variable has newlines at the end?); just use `$current_day` directly.

Comment: don't post bash questions unless you've run set -x and have the output

Comment: Your script is missing the line `cal > calendar.txt` and `current_day = "6"` should be `current_day="6"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `tput` commands insert special characters in your string. You can see the characters with `od`:

```
tput setaf 1 | od -c
0000000 033   [   3   1   m
0000005
tput sgr0 | od -c
0000000 033   (   B 033   [   m
0000006
```

You can use a different approach: remove everything that is not a space or digit.
You only want to perform this action on the lines with days of the month, not on the header lines.
As a result, for all lines with an `alpha` character in it, don't (that is `!`) use the remove command that will replace everything except digits and spaces `[^0-9 ]` with nothing.

```
sed -r '/[[:alpha:]]/!s/[^0-9 ]//g' calendar.txt
```